# how to fix curl django rest framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-3.1

how to fix curl django rest framework , I get error like this

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

this my curl

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signup -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"indah","password":"indah123"}'
```

and this my code ,

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            user = User.objects.create_user(data['username'], password=data['password'])
            user.save()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
            return JsonResponse({'token':str(token)}, status=201)
        except IntegrityError:
            return JsonResponse({'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'}, status=400)
```

and get error in line

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
```

I using cmd windows for curl what wrong with curl?

Comment: Try parsing `request.data` or `request.POST`.

Comment: As @DMalan suggested, try parsing `request.data`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible enhancements here (from the top to the bottom):

1. Adding decorator `@require_http_methods(['POST'])` allow you to delete this code `if request.method == 'POST':` and Django automatically will respond on requests with another method. This decorator could be imported `from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods`
2. Authentication is already built-in in the DRF with several options. Docs are [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) Your example could be Basic Auth or Token Auth. To simplify your example you can use a general JSON module from `import json`.
3. Your JSON from curl is here `request.data`. So if you will use `import json` you can get object like this `data = json.loads(request.data.encode())`.
4. You're responding with `201 Created`. It's good if the client won't check the response for `200 OK`.
5. The better way is to use DRF built-in auth.